# Create all posible combinations from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I've got a list

```
[
 [[[u'ANC'], [u'DEN', u'SFO'], [u'CHI', u'CLE', u'DEN', u'EWR', u'HOU', u'WAS'], [u'GSP']]], 
 [[[u'ANC'], [u'PDX', u'SEA'], [u'CHI', u'CLE', u'DEN', u'EWR', u'HOU', u'LAX', u'SFO', u'WAS'], [u'GSP']]]
]
```

list is already created from this text

```
ANC-DEN/SFO-CHI/CLE/DEN/EWR/HOU/WAS-GSP
ANC-PDX/SEA-CHI/CLE/DEN/EWR/HOU/LAX/SFO/WAS-GSP
```

I need to get all variants that could be done using that list:

```
ANC-SFO-EWR-GSP
ANC-SFO-CHI-GSP
ANC-SFO-CLE-GSP
ANC-DEN-EWR-GSP
ANC-PDX-EWR-GSP
ANC-SFO-HOU-GSP
ANC-SEA-LAX-GSP
ANC-SEA-EWR-GSP
ANC-SFO-ORD-GSP
ANC-PDX-LAX-GSP
ANC-PDX-CHI-GSP
ANC-DEN-CHI-GSP
ANC-SEA-SFO-GSP
ANC-PDX-SFO-GSP
ANC-SEA-CHI-GSP
ANC-SFO-DEN-GSP
ANC-PDX-HOU-GSP
ANC-SEA-HOU-GSP
ANC-DEN-HOU-GSP
ANC-DEN-CLE-GSP
ANC-PDX-CLE-GSP
ANC-SEA-CLE-GSP
ANC-DEN-ORD-GSP
ANC-PDX-ORD-GSP
ANC-PDX-DEN-GSP
ANC-SEA-DEN-GSP
ANC-SEA-ORD-GSP
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I've tried this 
`for a1 in mainhugeeveryarray:
 #print '++'
 for a2 in a1:
  for a3 in a2:
   for a4 in a3:
    print mainhugeeveryarray[j1][j2][j3][j4]
    j4 = j4+1
   j3 = j3+1
   j4 = 0
  j2 = j2+1 
  j3 = 0
  j4 = 0
 #print '++'
 j1 = j1+1
 j2 = 0
 j3 = 0
 j4 = 0`

Comment: @8am: For future reference, don't try to write multi-line code in comments. Either post it somewhere like pastebin.com and post a URL here, or edit the question.

Comment: They almost look like airport codes...

Comment: @JonClements: Actually, they look _exactly_ like airport codes. And most of them are international airports that are national or regional hubs (except for CHI instead of ORD, WAS instead of BWI/DCA/IAD, GSP instead of… whatever the big airport is in that part of the Carolinas). And apparently many travel systems use a few names like CHI and WAS as "metro codes" because they have no need to deal with the actual tiny local CHI airport, and there isn't a WAS at all, so…

Comment: @abarnert I only mention that, as if this is some kind of strange routing - it's not that simple to assume that a->b is also achievable by combinations there-of - but, that's not the question ;) (just mentioning as I had to build a flight search system, and I got **many** surprises from the data feeds!)

Comment: @JonClements: Last time I had to deal with this stuff, it _was_ guaranteed to be achievable, but it would probably cost you 8x as much to design your own 3-stop route from Anchorage to Spartanburg than to take one of the official ones, and of course nobody would help you make your connection or delay your next flight if the previous one was late. (And put that together with the fact that WAS could mean landing at BWI and taking off at Dulles…)

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my project. This are real fare routings (all codes should be usa airports)... If somebody is interested to learn more and may be work together on this project - you are welcome to contact me. :)

Comment: @8am nice of the offer - but I'm afraid I spent 9 months developing other systems that had to deal with international and internal flights for the globe (and although it was fun - not something I'd like to look at again ;))

Comment: @8am: From what I remember, airport code was more fun than insurance code and point-of-sale code, but just barely. At least _you_ get to write it in Python. Back in my day, we had to do it in the snow, uphill, wearing shoes made of PL/SQL procedures and C. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` and expand the list into arguments:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> test = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']]
>>> list(itertools.product(*test))
    [('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd')]
```

In your case, it'd be something like:

```
for row in data:
    for item in itertools.product(*row[0]):
        print '-'.join(item)
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like he wants something like `(itertools.product(*row[0]) for row in data)`. He's got a list of two lists, each one list of a bunch of lists, not just a list of one list of one list of a bunch of lists (as I originally thought, and as your answer assumes). But the basic principle is still exactly right.

Comment: Or, putting it all together: `['-'.join(prod) for row in data for col in row for prod in itertools.product(*col)]`. (The names `row` and `col` obviously assume it's some kind of table of lists of things, but whatever it actually is, the output is exactly what the OP asked for except for ordering.) Although I'd probably write it with `more_itertools.flatten` to get rid of two levels of nested `for`s in the comprehension, which would eliminate the need to guess the right names in the first place…

Comment: Blender and @abarnert: Thank you very much. Edited code version works great (I will only check if list of routes is unique)!

Comment: @8am: You know how to check if they're unique? (For something this small, where order doesn't matter, `list(set(x))` is good enough. Otherwise, look at the recipes in the `itertools` docs.)

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the tip. I'm learning python just for few days  (have few years experience just in php but moving forward). Thanks!

Comment: @8am: The sooner you start playing with `itertools` and get the hang of it, the sooner you'll become so spoiled that the thought of dealing with inferior languages like PHP again fills you with dread.